# Localized app crashes only on non-base language and only when not running with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, crash

Our iOS (Swift) app has English as the base language, and is localized to have Spanish as well. English works like a charm, but in Spanish devices, the app crashes within seconds of opening when it is not running along Xcode. Given this only happens when Xcode isn't running it's been hard to debug - any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Look at the crash log to see where and why it is crashing.

Comment: Post the crashes report pls

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure that I had the same problem as you, but I was getting a similar crash for non-base and non-localized languages. Originally I had the localized languages as

- English
- Chinese (Simplified)
- Chinese (Traditional)

Then I added Base and deleted English (moved it to base first) to give

- Base
- Chinese (Simplified)
- Chinese (Traditional)

After that it wasn't crashing anymore when I switched to another language.